# Download pdf invoice from PayPal

Tags: pdf, paypal, invoice

Is it possible to script the download pdf invoices from PayPal?
My customer has many invoices, created via the REST invoice API and wants to archive them in his own offline archive. I found out how to show the pdf directly via its invoice id but it requires me to be logged in (login/session cookies):

https://www.paypal.com/invoice/actions/render-pdf/INV2-ABCD-1234-EFGH-IJKL

I want to script the download of hundreds of invoice pdfs, so I would need an API call instead. Is there something unofficial?